# PlayN Font Support

Tags: fonts, truetype, playn

What kind of support do the PlayN or supporting libraries (like TriplePlay and others) provide in regards to non-standard fonts -- custom TrueType fonts in particular.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to register the font differently on each backend that you intend to use, but once the font is registered by name, you can use it like any built-in font by simply calling `PlayN.graphics().createFont(name, style, size)`.

The HTML5 backend registers fonts using [`@font-face` in CSS](http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/) on the page that loads your game. The Android and Java backends require some code to register the font, and in the iOS backend the font must be listed in your `Info.plist` file.

The PlayN Showcase sample application demonstrates custom font registration for all platforms:

- [Java](http://code.google.com/p/playn-samples/source/browse/showcase/java/src/main/java/playn/showcase/java/ShowcaseJava.java)
- [Android](http://code.google.com/p/playn-samples/source/browse/showcase/android/src/main/java/playn/showcase/android/ShowcaseActivity.java)
- [iOS](http://code.google.com/p/playn-samples/source/browse/showcase/ios/Info.plist)
- [HTML](http://code.google.com/p/playn-samples/source/browse/showcase/html/src/main/webapp/Showcase.html)

Comment: Thanks -- this is helpful.  Android and Java font registration would be invaluable; please let me know when you add that in. :)

Comment: Can you please be more precise about the fonts. I am trying to get a simple centering inside of SurfaceCanvas in ForPlay... and no luck so far, I have looked for FontMetrics but there is none for GWT... i just want to simply center a text inside the canvas.. If there is more simple way please yell :D [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211089/textcentering-inside-canvas-playn[/link]