# TextCentering inside Canvas PlayN

Tags: canvas, playn

I have one little problem:
I am trying go center a given text inside a Canvas with PlayN.
I do not have any FontMetrics, because GWT does not offer one, and simple repositioning depending of character number and fontsize just does not works :(..

Can somebody please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Graphics.layoutText` to create a `TextLayout`.

`TextLayout` provides the width and height of the text, which you can use to position it however you like and render it into a Canvas using `Canvas.drawText(TextLayout,x,y)`.

Comment: Thank you very much..I have an OlderVersion of ForPlay so it does not support TextLayout... so ill just have to bring it up to date