# For PlayN, can someone provide a simple code example showing how to load a font file?

Tags: playn

I'm looking for a simple example that loads a ttf file (in my case, `Inconsolata.ttf`) and creates a text layer.

Is it possible to do this in a platform-agnostic way? From this response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9116829/1093087), I get the impression it is not.

I am working on a simple proof-of-concept using the [TextDemo sample](http://code.google.com/p/playn-samples/source/browse/showcase/core/src/main/java/playn/showcase/core/text/TextDemo.java?spec=svn4636b14414a57f22f36ff78c4a04a94bc370f54a&r=4636b14414a57f22f36ff78c4a04a94bc370f54a#57) from the playn-samples showcase as a reference.

I'm presently a little confused on how to register the ttf file. Here's my code:

```
private void testCustomFont() {
    // text
    String text = "Hello, Cleveland!";

    // load font
    String fontName = "Inconsolata";
    Font.Style fontStyle = Font.Style.BOLD;
    Float fontSize = 24f;
    Font myFont = graphics().createFont(fontName, fontStyle, fontSize);

    // format text
    Integer fontColor = Color.rgb(0, 0, 255);
    TextFormat textFormat = new TextFormat().withFont(myFont).withTextColor(fontColor);

    // create font image layer
    ImageLayer textLayer = graphics().createImageLayer();
    TextLayout textLayout = graphics().layoutText(text, textFormat);
    CanvasImage textImage = graphics().createImage((int)Math.ceil(textLayout.width()), 
            (int)Math.ceil(textLayout.height()));
    textImage.canvas().drawText(textLayout, 0, 0);
    textLayer.setImage(textImage);


    // position text layer and add to root layer
    textLayer.setTranslation(20, 20);
    graphics().rootLayer().add(textLayer);
}
```

The projects is laid out like so:

```
/project
├── core
│   └── MyProject.java
└──  resources
    └──  fonts
         └──  Inconsolata.ttf
```

This displays the text but, as expected, not in the desired typeface.

Comment: I've sorta figured this out. Not the solution I was hoping for but did get the font loaded in Java version. I'll post code once self-answer moratorium lifts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, I would have like font-loading to have worked like image-loading with the asset manager:

```
String fontPath = "fonts/Inconsolata.ttf";
Font.Style fontStyle = Font.Style.BOLD;
Float fontSize = 24f;
Font myFont = assetManager().getFont(fontPath, fontStyle, fontSize);
```

That wasn't possible, so I looked into doing something like this:

```
private void registerFont() {
    if (platformType().equals(Platform.Type.JAVA)) {
        Platform platform = Platform.getJavaPlatformApi();
        platform.assets().setPathPrefix("com/klenwell/myproject/resources");
        platform.graphics().registerFont("Inconsolata", "fonts/Inconsolata.ttf");
    }
    else if (platformType().equals(Platform.Type.ANDROID)) {
        Platform platform = Platform.getAndroidPlatformApi();
        platform.assets().setPathPrefix("com/klenwell/myproject/resources");
        platform.graphics().registerFont("Inconsolata", "fonts/Inconsolata.ttf");
    }
    else if (platformType().equals(Platform.Type.HTML)) {
        // rely on CSS setting in HTML host file
    }
}
```

But there is no method like getJavaPlatformApi in the core Platform class. So as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9116829/1093087), "you have to register the font manually on each backend that you intend to use."

---

Following the example of the [TextDemo sample](http://code.google.com/p/playn-samples/source/browse/), this is how I would load the font in my example above for the Java and HTML platforms:

#### Java Platform

Update [game class](http://code.google.com/p/playn-samples/source/browse/showcase/java/src/main/java/playn/showcase/java/ShowcaseJava.java) in Java dir:

```
public class MyProjectJava {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JavaPlatform platform = JavaPlatform.register();
    platform.assets().setPathPrefix("com/klenwell/myproject/resources");
    platform.graphics().registerFont("Inconsolata", "fonts/Inconsolata.ttf");
    PlayN.run(new MyProject());
  }
}
```

#### HTML Platform

Edit the [HTML host file](http://code.google.com/p/playn-samples/source/browse/showcase/html/src/main/webapp/Showcase.html) under HTML snapshot directory:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MyProject Font Loading Example</title>
    <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: "Inconsolata";
        src: url(myproject/resources/fonts/Inconsolata.ttf);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="black">
    <script src="myproject/myproject.nocache.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Android Platform

To Be Announced

#### iOS Platform

To Be Announced

I haven't yet ventured into Android or iOS compilation yet, so I can't offer an example of those at present.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your question is covered on the [PlayN wiki's custom fonts page](https://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/CustomFonts).

> PlayN supports the use of custom fonts, but such fonts need to be integrated specially for each of the different backends that you wish to use in your game. TrueType (.ttf) fonts are supported by all backends. OpenType (.otf) fonts are supported by some backends (iOS, HTML5, Android).

The main steps seem to be:

1. Add the font file as an asset.
2. Register the font separately for each back end using `platform.graphics().registerFont()`.
3. Create a font object using `PlayN.graphics().createFont()`, and then use it as normal.