# In the HTML version of my PlayN game, how can I reliably load fonts so text displays on startup?

Tags: playn

I'm using v1.3.1 of PlayN. This issue is discussed in the following google groups thread but I'm not sure how to implement the suggestions proposed:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/playn/kiE2iEYJqM0

Perhaps someone can offer some sample code. Currently I'm following the technique referenced in the [HTML link](http://code.google.com/p/playn-samples/source/browse/showcase/html/src/main/webapp/Showcase.html) in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9116829/1093087

My problem: on the home screen of my game, I display some text using loaded fonts. Works fine in Java version. However, in HTML version, the text doesn't display initially. On the next screen, or if I later return to the home screen, text is properly displayed. So I concluded that it was due to the asynchronous loading of fonts as discussed in the google groups thread.

My remedy was to add a splash screen that displays an image for a few seconds, giving the fonts a chance to load, before redirecting to screen with the text on it. But no matter how long I set the delay, the text is still not displayed.

Here's my HTML file which loads my game and the fonts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>mygamePlayn</title>
    <!-- fonts -->
    <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: "DroidSans-Bold";
        src: url(mygame/fonts/DroidSans-Bold.ttf);
      }
      @font-face {
        font-family: "UbuntuMono";
        src: url(mygame/fonts/UbuntuMono-Bold.ttf);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="black">
    <script src="mygame/mygame.nocache.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's my core Java code that generates the text that's not initially displaying (but works otherwise):

```
public static CanvasImage generateTextImage(String text, String fontName,
    Integer fontSize, Integer fontColor, Style fontStyle, Integer padding) {
    Font font = graphics().createFont(fontName, fontStyle, fontSize);
    TextFormat fontFormat = new TextFormat().withFont(font).withTextColor(fontColor);

    TextLayout layout = graphics().layoutText(text, fontFormat);
    Integer width = (int) layout.width() + padding * 2;
    Integer height = (int) layout.height() + padding * 2;

    CanvasImage textImage = graphics().createImage(width, height);
    textImage.canvas().drawText(layout, padding, padding);

    return textImage;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've finally figured out a solution to my problem. It required using [Google WebFont Loader](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader) in the following somewhat roundabout fashion:

1) I saved the fonts -- in this case, [DroidSans-Bold](http://www.google.com/webfonts#UsePlace%3ause/Collection%3aDroid+Sans), [Inconsolata](http://www.google.com/webfonts#UsePlace%3ause/Collection%3aInconsolata), and [UbuntuMono-Bold](http://www.google.com/webfonts#UsePlace%3ause/Collection%3aUbuntu+Mono) -- in my PlayN project's `resources/fonts` directory.

2) In `resources/css`, I add a `fonts.css` stylesheet where I add the `@font-face` definitions for my locally saved fonts. My `fonts.css` file:

> ```
> @font-face {
>     font-family: DroidSans;
>     src: url('../fonts/DroidSans-Bold.ttf');
> }
> @font-face {
>     font-family: Inconsolata;
>     src: url('../fonts/Inconsolata.ttf');
> }
> @font-face {
>     font-family: UbuntuMono;
>     src: url('../fonts/UbuntuMono-Bold.ttf');
> }
> @font-face {
>     font-family: UbuntuMono;
>     font-weight: bold;
>     src: url('../fonts/UbuntuMono-Bold.ttf');
> }
> ```

Note: I use the same value for my font-family name as that which I used for the font names in my PlayN code. For example, I load the DroidSans font in my PlayN code like this:

```
Font font = graphics().createFont("DroidSans", fontStyle, fontSize);
```

3) I then use Google WebFont Loader in my game's html file (`MyGame.html`) to load the fonts before the game loads. My `MyGame.html` file:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <title>MyGame</title>
>     <style>
>       body {
>         background-color:black;
>         color:white;
>       }
>     </style>
>
>     <!-- Google AJAX Libraries API -->
>     <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
>     <script>
>         google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");
>         google.load("webfont", "1");
>
>       WebFontConfig = {
>         custom: { families: ['DroidSans', 'UbuntuMono'],
>           urls: [ 'mygame/css/fonts.css' ]
>         },
>         loading: function() {
>           console.log("loading fonts");
>         },
>         fontloading: function(fontFamily, fontDescription) {
>           console.log("loading font: " + fontFamily + "-" + fontDescription);
>         },
>         fontactive: function(fontFamily, fontDescription) {
>           console.log(fontFamily + "-" + fontDescription + " is active");        
>         },
>         fontinactive: function(fontFamily, fontDescription) {
>           console.log(fontFamily + "-" + fontDescription + " is INACTIVE");
>         },
>         active: function() {
>           console.log("font-loading complete");
>         },
>       };
>
>       google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
>         console.log("Google onLoad callback");
>         WebFont.load(WebFontConfig);
>       });
>     </script>
>
>   </head>
>
>   <body>
>     <div id="playn-root">
>         &nbsp;
>         <script src="mygame/mygame.nocache.js"></script>
>     </div>
>   </body>
>
> </html>
> ```

The console logging in the `WebFont.load` callbacks helped verify that the fonts were successfully loaded before the PlayN game code.

I would have preferred to use WebFont Loader with the fonts served through [googleapis.com](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid%20Sans), but I couldn't figure out how to sync up the references between my PlayN code and the stylesheet. (Now that I look at it, if I didn't want to host the fonts myself, I suppose I could have just used the same url listed in the googleapi.com stylesheets.) Whatever the case, this pattern seems to solve the problem.*

*For Google Chrome. I haven't tested any other browsers.

Comment: do the fonts on the html version look the same as in the java version?
in my case the html version has less height, it appears a couple of pixels cut-off on the bottom

Comment: It's been a while but there were minor differences as I remember. I wasn't looking for perfect fidelity in my case.